# Trigger Module Lazy Load Manually Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

Official documentation has quite a lot of information about how to load angular modules lazily. [[link here]](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

This basically makes the module load when user visits `/customers` or `/orders` routes.

However, I can't figure out how do I load a module when from another module.

In my application I have these modules:

- auth
- core
- events
- flash messages

One route of my `auth module` (profile page) has to use ngrx store from `events module`.

My code looks like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppState } from '../../app.store';
import { IUser } from '../auth.api.service';
import { selectUser } from '../store/auth.selectors';
import { IEvent } from '../../events/events.api.service';
import { selectAllEvents, selectIsLoading } from '../../events/store/events.selectors';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss'],
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;
  events$: Observable<IEvent[]>;
  user$: Observable<IUser>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.store.select(selectUser);
    this.isLoading$ = this.store.select(selectIsLoading);
    this.events$ = this.store.select(selectAllEvents);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**However, as you can expect this code does not work.** Because `../../events` is not loaded yet. **How do I load the module manually? Something like:**

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<AppState>,
) {
  this.user$ = this.store.select(selectUser);
  this.loadModule('../../events/events.module.ts').then(() => {
    this.isLoading$ = this.store.select(selectIsLoading);
    this.events$ = this.store.select(selectAllEvents);  
  })
}
```

Comment: Please update with any errors that you are getting and create a stackblitz if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular CLI bundler bundles up the modules based on two things:

1) If you have the modules set up for lazy loading (`loadChildren`), it will bundle the module up separately and provide it lazily.

2) HOWEVER, if there are any references to a lazy loaded module in any other module (by adding it to its `imports` array), it instead bundles the module with the referenced component.

So what should be happening is that if your events module is referenced from a component, it should be bundled with that component.

Do you have the module referenced in the `imports` array for the module containing the component that references it?

What error are you getting exactly?

BTW - I cover this in the "lazy loading" part of this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ&t=1120s

Answer (score 1):

You need not worry about loading the `../../events`. Since you have the import statement, the class/interface would be available in the module. If for some reason, you want to use features of other modules, you can add the module name in the `imports` array in the `@NgModule` declaration.